# Android : passing different information in INTENT, based on the receiver app

Tags: android, android-intent

I observed in eBay Android app that, if I share an item using WhatsApp - only URL gets displayed. But if I share the item with Gmail - a lot more gets displayed in the mail which includes URL, Item Name, Mail Subject, End Time of the Auction and a custom footer at the end of the mail.

I also wrote an app to test the behavior. Here is the relevant code :

```
 String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
 String subject = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT);
 String title = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE);
```

Only **sharedText** is non-null.

In fact, I iterated on **intent.getExtras().keySet()**, there is only one key : **Intent.EXTRA_TEXT**

**How is Gmail getting all the extra data?**

Comment: You must publish also the codes where you define and create the objects EXTRA_SUBJECT and EXTRA_SUBJECT

Comment: have a look at the entire `Bundle` and check if it's under some other key

Comment: @ci_ I iterated the entire intent.getExtras().keySet(), there is only one key present, Intent.EXTRA_TEXT. (I edited the question to reflect this)

Comment: You need to at least post the code where you set the extras. Ideally, it would be nice to see how you set the extras, how you pass them with the intent, and then how you retrieve them. Just saying "this is null" doesn't really offer any information to go on.

Comment: @drschultz I am not setting the extras. I am just listening to the SEND intent. In this case, listening to eBay's app.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for a sharing app to specify what data to send to which app, e.g. by using a custom chooser or by populating the default chooser with explicit intents using [Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS).
If that's the case your app receives an intent without the additional data that you see being shared to Gmail. I'm afraid there's nothing you can do about that as receiving app.